# Jenkins - SonarQube Integration: Webhook retrieves 403, where can I find logs?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, webhooks, sonarqube-scan

I have integrated SonarQube into a Build Pipeline according to this: [SonarQube Documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins)

I am using SonarQube Scanner for Maven.
The analysis works fine, the communication from Jenkins to SonarQube is okay.

To break the build if a Quality Gate is failed, I use waitForQualityGate() as described in the documentation.
This works, but only when I add a sleep statement before it.

It seems, that the Webhook in SonarQube, is not working.
The waitForQualityGate() Method waits forever.

The Webhook which I have configured in SonarQube looks like this:
`http://<my-jenkins>/jenkins/sonarqube-webhook/`

I have used the configured Url to trigger the webhook manually using curl from the sonarqube server (I have manipulated the payload and added the related taskId which has been created by the build job in jenkins). The waitForQualityGate() Method retrieves the manually triggered webhook and everything works as expected.

But SonarQube can not send the webhook request to Jenkins.

I used the SonarQube Api to get more information: `http://<my-sonar-qube>/sonarqube/api/webhooks/deliveries?ceTaskId=<task-id>`

There I can see, that the status is '403' and 'success=false'. But calling exactly the same url from the sonarqube server via curl succeeds.

In which Jenkins and SonarQube logfiles can I find detailed information about the webhook request/response?

Jenkins Version: 2.89.2
SonarQube Version: 6.7

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the Webhook URL (obfuscated if you like) configured in SonarQube. Does it include a trailing `/`?

Comment: I have added the Url to the question. Yes, it includes a trailing `/`.

Comment: The webhook calls should show up in your Jenkins log. Do they?

Comment: In Jenkins log I can only find the manually triggered webhook calls.

Comment: You mean when you manually invoke the Jenkins URL configured in your webhook? Any errors in the SQ logs?

Comment: Yes, I have manually invoked the Jenkins URL which is configured in SQ.
Where are the log files located? I could find in SQ Web UI: Administration > System > Download Logs. But I could not find any webhook information in these logs. Log Level is set to Info.

Comment: `$SONARQUBE_HOME/logs` @nrpl

Comment: in web.log I have found the following INFO Message:
'2018.04.16 12:23:09 INFO  web[AWLOXkCj/laDJkoQAAAq][o.a.t.u.h.Parameters] Character decoding failed. Parameter [key] with value [sonar.webhooks.global.jenkins.name%value=Jenkins] has been ignored. Note that the name and value quoted here may be corrupted due to the failed decoding. Use debug level logging to see the original, non-corrupted values.'

The webhook name is 'Jenkins', the url 'http://<jenkinshostname>/jenkins/sonarqube-webhook/'
The hostname does not contain any special characters.

Answer (score 0):

with
`less PATH_TO_YOUR_SONAR_LOGS/access.log | grep /api/ce/submit`
you should see the trigger from sonar - never the less not the call itself :(